# Add and push commit tag in GitLab CI/CD job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to add and push a commit tag using the GitLab CI/CD configuration file?

In my use case I have a `release` stage that uploads a python package and it's associated documentation, and then only after those succeed I would like to tag the commit with the version number.

Comment: inlcuding the version tag with your code does not scale. Moreover, modifying a repo by pushing a tag from within a pipeline is a sideeffect that should be avoided. is not how to create releases in gitlab. Rather see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520905/how-to-create-releases-in-gitlab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a job using your `release` stage in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` with these lines :

```
tag_commit:   
  stage: release   
  script:
    - git tag -a v1.0 <COMMIT_ID> -m "Message here"
    - git push origin v1.0
```

Comment: tried that but got

$ git push --force-with-lease origin "$RELEASE_VERSION" "HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"

remote: You are not allowed to upload code.

fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.xxx.de/xxx/xxx.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Answer (score 2):

GitLab exposes REST API for tagging. Example:

```
tag_it:
  stage: release
  script:
    - curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/repository/tags?tag_name=test&ref=master"
```

See more info in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/tags.html#create-a-new-tag.