# How can I delete binaries attached to a tag/release in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, release-management

While [adding files to a tag in order to create a release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013457/how-to-store-releases-binaries-in-gitlab) I incorrectly attached the wrong file. I modified the tag again to remove the bad file link, and uploaded a new one. However, where does the wrong file go? I can't see anywhere in Gitlab's administration interface a way to delete the previously uploaded file.

For clarification, the files I refer to are those I drag in the web UI to attach to a release tag and appear in a path like `https://gitlab.com/user/repo/uploads/hash/filename`.